# GTM variable returning undefined

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-tag-manager

I am writing a custom GTM variable to check the classname of the table component on a page.

This works in the Google Chrome console, but keeps returning `undefined` in the GTM debugger.

```
function(){
  return $("table").className;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an educated guess, it works in the console because when you type in the console the page is already loaded. If you try to use this in a tag that is triggered on page view (container loaded as it is now called) then the DOM element will be not present, and the variable is undefined. You would need a trigger that fires on domReady or Pageload, or on a custom event that is fired after the table element is rendered by the browser.

As a side not, there is not need to use jQuery or other libraries in GTM. GTM contains its own selector engine, and you can just create a DOM type variable (which also will work only after the DOM has rendered), so there is a dependency you can avoid.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Using `$("table")` did not work but using `document.getElementByTagName("table")` worked.